# Not getting the whole records using php toolkit

Tags: php

I am using the PHP Toolkit and execute the below query

SELECT AssetId,CaseNumber, Chat_Confirmation_Taken__c, ClosedDate,Component__c, Description,Id, IsEscalated,Issue_Description__c,RecordTypeId,Status, Subject, type from Case

In this query i am not getting recordTypeId,type,Component__c and Issue_Description__c but if i execute the same using the Real Force Explorer tool it give me the whole result.

I got frustrated in finding the solution of it.Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: are you using same user for both Force Explorer & php toolkit?

Comment: yes i am using the same user